# Pandas: filter on grouped and aggregated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) which is based on a read-in excel list. The data has multiple columns and rows with one unique identifier. I want to plot the data through a PyQT interface based on some user selection (checkboxes), but I cannot select one unique row for plotting.

The data looks like this:

```
| Experiment | Data 1 | Data 2   |
| --------   | ------ | -------- |
| Exp1       |    0   |    1     |
| Exp2       |    0   |    2     |
| Exp3       |    1   |    2     |
| Exp1       |    1   |    2     |
| Exp3       |    2   |    2     |
```

After

```
df.groupby('Experiment').agg(list)
```

I get this:

```
| Experiment | Data 1 | Data 2   |
| ---------- | ------ | -------- |
| Exp1       | [0, 1] | [1, 2]   |
| Exp2       | [0]    | [2]      |
| Exp3       | [1, 2] | [2, 2]   |
```

I can use this for plotting e.g. with [pyqtgraph](/questions/tagged/pyqtgraph). However, after the user makes a selection, only that specific experiment is supposed to be plotted (e.g. Exp3).

I tried filtering on the aggregated list with

```
.filter(lambda x: x['Culture ID']=='Exp3')
```

but it says that `'function' object is not iterable` and I have a feeling this is the wrong approach.

Is there a way for me to get for example the index of the Experiment name (e.g. Exp3) so that I can access it this way or can someone explain how I could filter or access one of the rows based on the string/experiment key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby('Experiment').agg(list).query('index == "Exp3"')
```

output:

```
              Data 1    Data 2
Experiment      
Exp3          [ 1 , 2 ] [ 2 , 2 ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not aware of the query function. Can you briefly explain why I query against index and not against 'Experiment'?

Comment: becuz `groupby `+ `agg` make `by('Experiment')`  to index. run `df.groupby('Experiment').agg(list)`

Comment: I was not fast enough with my previous comment: Can I use query and keep Exp3 in a variable? The user might want to search for 'ExpX' instead Exp3. The '' prevent using a string variable currently, right?

Comment: "Exp3" is string value. User can search for value "ExpX" instead value "Exp3".

Comment: To clarify: ExpX gets passed to a function that is supposed to do the plotting. This function transmits the key in form of a string. I was thinking about something like:

`value = key` (key could be Exp1 or Exp2....)
`df.groupby('Experiment').agg(list).query('index == @value')`

however that does not seem to work. Also, thanks for the help!

Comment: I solved it by creating a separate string variable and query on that. Thank you very much :)